# Select Distinct using a join

Tags: mysql

> ```
> select DISTINCT cid,cname,tid
>     from colors c
>     left join tags t on t.tname = c.cname;
> ```

**colors:**

> cid cname
>
> 1 red
>
> 2 blue
>
> 3 green

**tags:**

> tid tname
>
> 1 red
>
> 2 red
>
> 3 blue
>
> 4 green

**Current Result:**

> 1 red 1
>
> 1 red 2
>
> 2 blue 3
>
> 3 green 4

**Expected Result:**

> 1 red 1
>
> 2 blue 3
>
> 3 green 4

Comment: you need to group result using cid.

Comment: use `group by` instead of distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should match your expected result

```
select cid,cname,tid
from colors c
left join tags t on t.tname = c.cname;
group by c.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    cid, cname, tid
from
    colors c
        left join
    tags t ON t.tname = c.cname
GROUP BY c.cname,c.cid,t.tid;
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY tag name

```
select DISTINCT cid,cname,tid
from colors c
left join tags t on t.tname = c.cname;
GROUP BY t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have mysql to try this but this should help you. One more thing is you can not directly use `tid` into your query you need to take count of it.

```
select  cid, cname, count(tid)
    from Color c
    left join tags t on t.name = c.cname
GROUP BY cname;
```

here is [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f98ce/1) for it

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`

```
select cid,cname,tid
from colors c
left join tags t on t.tname = c.cname
group by cid,cname,tid;
```